# Android replace the current fragment with another fragment

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I just started with fragment design for HoneyComb. I created two fragments. When i click  a button in the left side fragment, a new fragment is created in right side. Meanwhile when i click a button in the right fragment(ie. DetialsFragment in my code below should be replaced by another fragment.
main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <fragment class="com.fragment.example.Titles"
        android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentExample.java

```
public class FragmentExample extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Titles.java

```
public class Titles extends Fragment {
    public FragmentTransaction ft;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main1, null);
        Button button1 = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setText("santhosh");
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);
                    if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != 1) {
                        // Make new fragment to show this selection.
                        details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(1);

                        // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing
                        // fragment with this one inside the frame.
                        ft
                                = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.add(R.id.details, details, "detail");
                        ft.setTransition(
                                FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
            }

        });
        return v;
    }
}
```

DetailsFragment.java

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Create a new instance of DetailsFragment, initialized to
     * show the text at 'index'.
     */
    Titles title = new Titles();
    String[] titles = {"Title1", "Title2", "Title3", "Title4"};
    public static DetailsFragment newInstance(int index) {
        DetailsFragment f = new DetailsFragment();

        // Supply index input as an argument.
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("index", index);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            // Currently in a layout without a container, so no
            // reason to create our view.
            return null;
        }
        Button button = new Button(getActivity());
        button.setText("Next");
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Then provided your button is showing and the click event is being fired you can call the following in your click event:

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
ft.commit();
```

and if you want to go back to the DetailsFragment on clicking back ensure you add the above transaction to the back stack, i.e.

```
ft.addToBackStack(null);
```

Or am I missing something? Alternatively some people suggest that your activity gets the click event for the button and it has responsibility for replacing the fragments in your details pane.

Comment: Providing fragment tag is optional. You can do `ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace());`

Comment: Also don't forget `getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();`

Comment: The buttons doesn't go away of the previous fragment. The buttons of the old fragment are still visible on the top of the new fragment.

Comment: @Santanu the reason it is happening is that the background color of the view is not set. Make it white and then it will work

Comment: @Santanu Check the R.id.details is the id of the parent fragment container, not of the current fragment.  This fixed this issue for me.

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal can you explain how this resolves the issue? I would need to change the toolbar shared by other activities to have a white background and would like to know the logic behind this fix

Answer (score 6):

### Latest Stuff

Okay. So this is a very old question and has great answers from that time. But a lot has changed since then.

Now, in 2020, if you are working with Kotlin and want to change the fragment then you can do the following.

1. Add Kotlin extension for Fragments to your project.

In your app level `build.gradle` file add the following,

```
dependencies {
    def fragment_version = "1.2.5"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    // Testing Fragments in Isolation
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
}
```

2. Then simple code to replace the fragment,

In your activity

```
supportFragmentManager.commit {
    replace(R.id.frame_layout, YourFragment.newInstance(), "Your_TAG")
    addToBackStack(null)
}
```

References

[Check latest version of Fragment extension](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)

[More on Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui#kotlin)

Comment: This works for Kotlin as of today, just replace the version with current version from here `https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment`

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code. it’s very easy method for push new fragment from old fragment.

```
private int mContainerId;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private final static String TAG = "DashBoardActivity";

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String TAG) {

    try {
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(mContainerId, fragment, tag);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}
```

Comment: what is mcontainerid

Comment: @Ayoub is u view id.. example linearLayout.getId() in java

Answer (score 2):

Use `android.support.v4.app` for FragmentManager & FragmentTransaction in your code, it has worked for me.

```
DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.details,detailsFragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a handle to an existing fragment you can just replace it with the fragment's ID.

Example in Kotlin:

```
fun aTestFuction() {
   val existingFragment = MyExistingFragment() //Get it from somewhere, this is a dirty example
   val newFragment = MyNewFragment()
   replaceFragment(existingFragment, newFragment, "myTag")
}

fun replaceFragment(existing: Fragment, new: Fragment, tag: String? = null) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(existing.id, new, tag).commit()
}
```

Comment: val existingFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.first()

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer (Working for Overlap problem as well)**

@aniket-thakur(https://stackoverflow.com/users/2396539/aniket-thakur) gave correct answer. Thank you for that!

But, `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated, so following code did work for me.

```
final FragmentTransaction ft = getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new GalleryFragment(), "NewFragmentTag");
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple how to replace with Fragment.

```
DataFromDb changeActivity = new DataFromDb();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.changeFrg, changeActivity);
    transaction.commit();
```