# Button Listener for button in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android and trying to learn on my own. But I am having a tough time with Fragments. I am creating a simple application to learn fragments. I think it may seem silly but I really can't get this to work.

All I want to do is on the click of a button (buttonSayHi) in Fragment_One, Fragment_One should be replaced by Fragment_Two.

I am not sure when the Fragment code is called and where am I supposed to write my code to call the second fragment. I get the error: Unable to start Activity component.

However, the code works fine if I discard the listener for button and the fragment is displayed within the activity.

I have done considerable research, read the fragments tutorial on developer.android.com and also the tutorial by Lars Vogella. I think my concepts are not clear.

Any help will be appreciated.

The following is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayoutFragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

</FrameLayout>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSayHi"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Say Hi" 
        android:onClick="onButtonClicked"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewResult"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I will say Hi!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    View view;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        Fragment fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentOne);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    protected void onButtonClicked()
    {
        if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonSayHi){
            Fragment fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentTwo);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();   

        }

    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttutorial;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    View view;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        return view;
    }

//  protected void onButtonClicked()
//  {
//      if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonSayHi){
//          Fragment fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
//
//          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentTwo);
//          fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
//
//          fragmentTransaction.commit();   
//
//      }
//
//  }
}
```

I have commented out the on click code in the fragment. I have also tried implementing the onClickListener in the fragment.

FragmentTwo.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttutorial;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        return view;    
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have removed the line android:onClick="onButtonClicked" from my code in XML. And edited the following files but it still does not work. Can you guys provide me a working example without the android:onClick="onButtonClicked" line.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttutorial;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    View view;
    Fragment fragmentOne;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentOne);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();       
    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
package com.example.fragmenttutorial;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    View view;
    Fragment fragmentTwo;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        Button buttonSayHi = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSayHi);
        buttonSayHi.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();

        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentTwo);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

        fragmentTransaction.commit();   

    }
}
```

Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: onClick takes a view as a parameter

        `protected void onButtonClicked(View V)`

Comment: ...and the method must also be public...not protected.

Comment: @Bot check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Fragment onClick button Method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192386/android-fragment-onclick-button-method)

Answer (score 69):

Your fragment class should implement OnClickListener

```
public class SmartTvControllerFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
```

Then get view, link button and set onClickListener like in example below

```
 View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.smart_tv_controller_fragment, container, false);
    upButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.smart_tv_controller_framgment_up_button);
    upButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
 }
```

And then add onClickListener method and do what you want.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 //do what you want to do when button is clicked
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.textView_help:
            switchFragment(HelpFragment.TAG);
            break;
        case R.id.textView_settings:
            switchFragment(SettingsFragment.TAG);
            break;
    }
}
```

This is my example of code, but I hope you understood

Comment: but op has `android:onClick="onButtonClicked"` in xml

Comment: I prefer writing onClick Listeners inside fragment and not to put it in XML. It's easier to find where is onClick method and what it is doing. So I suggest to remove that line in xml :)

Comment: but that's not what op wants

Comment: At 'onCreateView()', don't you mean its...

'View.findViewById(R.id.smart_tv_controller_framgment_up_button);'

and not...

'V.findViewById(R.id.smart_tv_controller_framgment_up_button);'

for this code line?

Comment: implement OnClickListener on fragment is not worked for me, @Yao Hao's answer work for me.

Comment: Thank you. However, it should be noted that this answer is not reusable. If the programmer should want to use 2 or more buttons, they'd have to take a different approach.

Answer (score 9):

Use your code

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

    View view;
    Fragment fragmentTwo;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        Button buttonSayHi = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSayHi);
        buttonSayHi.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }
```

But I think is better handle the buttons in this way:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.buttonSayHi:
            /** Do things you need to..
               fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();

               fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentTwo);
               fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

               fragmentTransaction.commit();  
            */
            break;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: That second example is a neat trick. What are the pros and cons of doing it that way?

Comment: This is reusable

Answer (score 4):

**Fragment Listener**

If a `fragment` needs to communicate `events` to the `activity`, the `fragment` should define an `interface` as an inner type and require that the `activity` must `implement` this `interface`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {
  // ...
  // Define the listener of the interface type
  // listener is the activity itself
  private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

  // Define the events that the fragment will use to communicate
  public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onRssItemSelected(String link);
  }

  // Store the listener (activity) that will have events fired once the fragment is attached
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
      if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
        listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
      } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
      }
  }

  // Now we can fire the event when the user selects something in the fragment
  public void onSomeClick(View v) {
     listener.onRssItemSelected("some link");
  }
}
```

and then in the `activity`:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class RssfeedActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
  MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {
    DetailFragment fragment;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssfeed);
      fragment = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
  }

  // Now we can define the action to take in the activity when the fragment event fires
  @Override
  public void onRssItemSelected(String link) {
      if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
          fragment.setText(link);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this is what Google recommends, this tends to create a **God Activity** where everything is handled by the container Activity. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: God, this is a lot

Answer (score 4):

You only have to get the view of activity that carry this fragment and this could only happen when your fragment is already created

override the `onViewCreated()` method inside your fragment and enjoy its magic :) ..

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.YOURBUTTONID);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
         //place your action here
         }
    });
```

Hope this could help you ;

Answer (score 0):

While you are declaring onclick in XML then you must declair method and pass View v as parameter and make the method public...

```
Ex:
//in xml
android:onClick="onButtonClicked"


// in java file
public void onButtonClicked(View v)
{
//your code here
}
```

Comment: ashfak, in your case the Java code has to be in Activity, can't be in Fragment. By specifying onButtonClicked it assumes the public void onButtonClicked(View) will be in Activity

Answer (score 0):

```
    //sure run it i will also test it
//we make a class that extends with the fragment
    public class Example_3_1 extends Fragment  implements OnClickListener
    {
       View vi;
        EditText t;
        EditText t1;
        Button bu;
 // that are by defult function of fragment extend class
     @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,BundlesavedInstanceState) 
       {        
           vi=inflater.inflate(R.layout.example_3_1, container, false);// load the xml file 
           bu=(Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.button1);// get button id from example_3_1 xml file
           bu.setOnClickListener(this); //on button appay click listner
           t=(EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editText1);// id get from example_3_1 xml file
           t1=(EditText) vi.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
          return vi; // return the view object,that set the xml file  example_3_1 xml file
       }
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)//on button click that called
       {

          switch(v.getId())// on run time get id what button os click and get id
          {
          case R.id.button1:        // it mean if button1 click then this work
           t.setText("UMTien");     //set text 
           t1.setText("programming");
           break;
          }
    }     }
```

Comment: Can you please give some details about your answer?

Comment: @sandhu - "code only" answers are acceptable at Stack Overflow, but they should usually be avoided. Some text with the code to briefly describe the solution is usually very helpful to the person asking the question. See [Down Vote “code only” answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95470/173448) for a discussion on the criteria.

Comment: Thanks sir. next time careful and explain the answer line by line

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
private OnClickListener mDisconnectListener;
mDisconnectListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

...

... onCreateView(...){

mButtonDisconnect = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_disconnect);
mButtonDisconnect.setOnClickListener(mDisconnectListener);
...
}
```

Comment: no need to implement OnClickListener on the fragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

### FragmentOne.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    View rootView;        

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSayHi);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onButtonClicked(v);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

  public void onButtonClicked(View view)
  {
          //do your stuff here..           
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    ft.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, new FragmentTwo(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
    ft.commit(); 

    ft.addToBackStack(null);    
  }
}
```

check this : [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163104/android-replace-the-current-fragment-with-another-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass view object into onButtonClicked function. getView() does not seem to work as expected inside fragment.
Try this code for your FragmentOne fragment

PS. you have redefined object view in your original FragmentOne code.

```
package com.example.fragmenttutorial;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class FragmentOne extends Fragment{

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        onButtonClicked(view);
        return view;
    }

  protected void onButtonClicked(View view)
  {
      if(view.getId() == R.id.buttonSayHi){
          Fragment fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();

          fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, fragmentTwo);
          fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

          fragmentTransaction.commit();   

     }
```