# Why is Android system looking for onClick listener for a button present in a Fragment, in the host Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, onclick, onclicklistener

First of all this excerpt from the logcat:

```
...
03-17 13:14:04.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2688): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method readInInput(View) in the activity class tests.test.Testee.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button
...
03-17 13:14:04.887: E/AndroidRuntime(2688): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: readInInput [class android.view.View]
...
```

I am getting this error in the following SSCCE. I initially thought that probably the `onClick` listeners for controls in fragment are defined in host Activity, but [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711433/button-listener-for-button-in-fragment-in-android#answer-18711612) says that they are defined in the fragment. **So why am I getting this Exception?**

***SSCCE:***

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void startInitialConfiguration(View view) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ChooseFragment chooseFragment = new ChooseFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mainActivity_frameLayout, chooseFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FA5858"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mainActivity_button"
        android:onClick="startInitialConfiguration" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/mainActivity_frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**ChooseFragment:**

```
public class ChooseFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose, container, false); 
    }

    public void readInInput(View view) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBF00")); 
    }

}
```

**fragment_choose:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummyText" />

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dummyText"
        android:onClick="readInInput" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**res/values/strings.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Testee</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="mainActivity_button">Start</string>
    <string name="dummyText">Dummy Text</string>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define the click listener in the xml itself then the callback goes to the Activity containing the fragment. To get the callback in the Fragment you gotta assign the click listener in Java.

First get a reference to the button in the Fragment's onCreateView() method using `button = expandedLayout.findViewById(R.id.viewId)`, then set a click listener on it using `button.setOnClickListener()`.