# App stop working after button click

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

so I´m making an app with fragments and I want a sound on button click. Everything works except when I click on the button the app stop working. I put an onclick method named *playAnother* on the button. I think the problem might be there in .java file: [image: here is screen] I dont know what to do I´m total beginner. Have a nice day!

Comment: A note about the tags: *JavaScript* is not the same as *Java*

Comment: post code here rather than posting the image of code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `playAnother(View view)` must be in your Activity, not in fragment.

OR

If you want to handle the button click in your fragment you can give your button an id:

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button"
  .
  .
```

And then in your **fragment**'s `onCreateView()`

```
public View onCreateView(...) {
    // First we save the reference to the views of your fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_three, container, false);

    // Then we need to find the button-view
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    // And finally we can register OnClickListener for the button
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Handle your button click here
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: so all i have to do is put everything from FragmentThree.java to MainActivity.java and leave button in fragment_three.xml?

Comment: Maybe that would work, but what is the purpose to have a Fragment then? It would be better to handle the clicks in your fragment. Follow my advice below the word "OR"

Answer (score 0):

Has your button's onClick been set in fragment_three.xml layout:

```
<Button
 .
 .
 . 
 android:onClick="playAnother" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18711433/button-listener-for-button-in-fragment-in-android this should help you out. Fragments cannot reference onClick events from layouts