# Show fragment when menu item is clicked in new NavigationView

Tags: android, fragment

I am a beginner using Android Studio to create an app and when I click a navigation menu item I want to show a different fragment. I have searched tutorials but I have not found how to use it.

For example, in the template, when I click camera it should show a camera fragment, gallery would show a gallery fragment, and so on:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        // Handle the camera action
        // How do I display fragment?
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android replace the current fragment with another fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163104/android-replace-the-current-fragment-with-another-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

Your Activity should include a `FrameLayout`. In `onNavigationItemSelected()` you create the `Fragment` for the camera, gallery, etc. Then you put this fragment into the `FrameLayout`.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment newFragment; // This is the fragment you want to put into the FrameLayout

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_camara) {
        newFragment = new CameraFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        newFragment = new GalleryFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
        // [...]
    }

    // Let's put the new fragment into the FrameLayout
    // If you use the support action bar, use getSupportFragmentManager(), else getFragmentManager()
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment); // R.id.fragment_container = FrameLayout ID
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: @SwamyVeera as he explained in the comments of the answer, you need to replace that line with whatever the id is for the FrameLayout in your activity's XML layout.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try like this,

```
final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImagesRef.child("Profile Images").child(currentUserID + ".jpg");
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Uri > () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                    RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image").setValue(downloadUrl).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener < Void > () {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task < Void > task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Your picture Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Problem occurred while tryng to save your picture..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Your picture did NOT saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```