# Android replace fragment with existing version

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

Can someone explain why this code isn't working?

```
    Fragment f = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);

    if (f == null) {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.protokoll_content, fragment, tag).commit();
    } else {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.protokoll_content, f).commit();
    }
```

I don't think you need much more to get what I'm trying to do, and I don't think the rest of the code is relevant to the problem. I'm like 99% certain this is the trouble zone.

I'm simply trying to load an existing version of a fragment by calling it by its tag.

In my mind the above code would execute as follows:

IF (the fragment has no existing instance) { create a new one with a unique tag and replace the existing fragments in the container with it }

OTHERWISE (the fragment DOES have an existing instance) { load that existing version instead of creating a new one and replace the current fragment with the found existing fragment }

**Edit**

Slightly updated code. Same problem, new fragments are made instead of existing instances of the fragments getting loaded.

**Clarification**

New fragments are made each time instead of existing ones getting loaded. If I write something, go to a new fragment and then try to go back the the old fragment all the text is wiped because new fragments get made instead of old ones getting loaded.

Comment: have you debugged for the value of tag??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android replace the current fragment with another fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163104/android-replace-the-current-fragment-with-another-fragment)

Comment: your `if` condition says if fragment is null you are loading `null fragment`. what exactly you are doing. ? `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_content, fragment, tag).commit();`

Comment: Bharat - thanks, stupid mistake... no sleep and coding does not compute... the original problem still persists, new fragments are made not existing instances getting loaded

Answer (score 0):

Below code is used to **add fragment if no fragment is added to layout**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment1 fragment1 = new Fragment1();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment1, "fragment1");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

> Above code will add Fragment1 to R.id.fragment

Below code is used to **replace a fragment with another in a layout**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
Fragment2 fragment2 = new Fragment2();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment2, "fragment2");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

> Above code will replace a fragment with another in a layout

Comment: Thanks  but unfortunately the problem isnt that I cant create/add/replace fragments, it's that I dont want new instances of old fragments, I want to load previous instances. So when I edit the text in a fragment and then load another fragment, then try to go back to the old one all the text is wiped because it is a new fragment getting loaded.

Comment: Store edited text in sharedpreference before replacing.. When you reload previous fragment, take vales from sharepref and store back. Thats a way to restore fragment back to previous look

Comment: Ljas Ahamed - but when adding to back stack you can simply press back button and all the text is still there, so the function exists to get it back without using a store text and recreate fragment option. :P