# Android navigation through multiple layouts

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

i have this app that i want to have a specific way of navigation. And so i made a research but i got confused. And i am begginer in android development. 
i want to ask what kind of layout or anything i can use to achieve that. I dont search for super specific answer, just what is the thing that is doing the job i want. So there it is:

[image]

the blue block("choose a brand" view) has to be on that position at all times and only changing the text if needed. I want when one image button is clicked the whole green block with the image grid  change into another xml layout. I want to call multiple layouts in the green block when i interact with the buttons of those layouts. Atm the green block is an `<include layout ="layout.xml"/>`

I really apreciate any answer. Sorry if is basic but i really tried to find the thing i need but so far i see solutions that prevent me from using simple inflaters. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation about fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use fragments for this scenario.

You will have a LinearLayout where the first element will be your blue block.
The second element will be a FrameLayout that you will change into the Fragment you need (usually it will have the ID container).

Create a Fragment and set the layout your layout.xml file.
Create a second Fragment with the desired layout you would like to change the green block.

As you click on a imageButton you will have to change the current Fragment with the desired one. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment) you will see how to send objects to fragments.

You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163104/android-replace-the-current-fragment-with-another-fragment) a way to switch between fragments. In the ft.replace method the first id is the FrameLayout you will use as a container(see above).

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.container, new NewFragmentToReplace(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
ft.commit();
```

Be careful when you import fragments. If you use the support package you will have to use `getSupportFragmentManager();`

Read more on the [android developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) about fragments

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Fragment class, which can be used as reusable code that can be linked to a UI/layout.

From android documentation:

> To create a dynamic and multi-pane user interface on Android, you need to encapsulate UI components and activity behaviors into modules that you can swap into and out of your activities. You can create these modules with the Fragment class, **which behaves somewhat like a nested activity that can define its own layout** and manage its own lifecycle.

[Read more here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html)

Comment: i see. Seems like this is the thing i need. I will follow this way and see. Thanks a lot :)